# From uploading CSV file to saving him as JSON in mongodb in server side node.js && react.js web application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, csv

I'm building node.js web application using react.js on client side and mongoDB, and I'm trying to upload a CSV file, sending it to the server side as Formdata object.

On the server side, I need to open the CSV file locally and convert it to JSON object so I could deploy the data in my mongoDB storage.

Comment: it is better to open csv on the frontend(read csv) and send all data into body in array format.

Comment: How can i open CSV file that the user gust uploaded on the fronted side? @Ahmad

Comment: please follow this [tutorial](https://web.dev/read-files/) for reading files using `new FileReader()`